# Не воспроизводится музыка - Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При запуске игры, через 20 секунд включается панель, и вызывается метод, в этом методе запускается музыка. Проблема: после запуска метода, музыка не проигрывается, стоит нажать на экран она начинает проигрываться, как бороться собственно с этим?

```
void Update()   {

        if (isCheckInMethod) {
            if (idle) {
                idle = false;
            }
            last_ui = Time.time;
        } 


        if (Input.anyKeyDown ) {
            if (idle) {
                idle = false;
            }
            last_ui = Time.time;

        }
        if ((Time.time - last_ui) > idle_lim) {
            idle = true;

            ButtonsController.Instance.OnCameAnimal(); // вызывается метод через 20 сек
        }
```

Сам метод:

```
public void OnCameAnimal() 
{
    CameAnimal.SetActive (true);
    animalsCameCall [randomAnimalShow].SetActive (true);
    StartCoroutine(SoundManager.Instance.SoundRing ()); // запуск музыки
}
```

```
public  IEnumerator SoundRing() // Сам метод запуска музыки
    {
        soundRing.Play ();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(soundSourceCallAnimal.clip.length);
        ButtonsController.Instance.OnClickCameAnimalClose ();
}
```

Comment: А продебажить никак? Сделай лог на вызов звука в OnCameAnimal(), если через 20 сек само не запускается, проблема в Update. Я таки предполагаюу тебя last_ui хрен пойми чему равно в начале игры, пока не нажмешь по экрану(Input.anyKeyDown). И чему равно idle_lim?

Comment: в логах выводится и в OnCameAnimal и в SoundRing. last_ui = 0.0f, idle_lim = 20.0f;

Comment: А что делает idle(true/false)? Такое ощущение, что у вас пауза, а при нажатии на экран, пауза слетает. B где-нибудь блокировка звука при паузе. Дебажьте дальше, прям в update  посмотрите какое состояние у soundRing запущен ли, меняется ли время проигрывания(isPlaying и Time).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Добавил еще bool isCheckStatus, проблема была в  last_ui = Time.time; он блокировал звук.

```
void Update()   
{

        if (Input.anyKeyDown) 
        {
            if (idle) {
                idle = false;}
             last_ui = Time.time;
        }
        if (isCheckStatus) 
        {
            last_ui = Time.time;
            isCheckStatus = false;
        } 
        if ((Time.time - last_ui) > idle_lim) 
        {
            idle = true;
            EventManager.Instance.Method ();
            isCheckStatus = true;
        }
}
```